# Why Does a Cracked or Loose Distributor Cap Cause Problems?

Tags: ignition, cam-position-sensor

Why does a distributor cap that is improperly sealed, due to being either loose or cracked, cause problems such as erratic idle or not starting?

Could a loose cap cause problems with an optical rotor with slits style camshaft position sensor?

Comment: I think the key is that "improperly sealed" implies that it's not lined up correctly.  That means timing could be slightly off, or you just have poor contact with the rotor - both of which are going to cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crack can form a track that moisture can collect in.  This track of moisture can then create a path for the HT current to short down to the engine ground, in so doing, bypassing the required destination of a spark plug.  When a distributor has had a fault like this for a while you can visibly see a carbon build up following the path that the HT current has taken.  These tracks can form even when a crack is not visible, maybe moisture got inside the cap and condensed on the inside wall of the cap.